# using python 2.5 to subtract two lists

Tags: python

i have made a function which uses  subtraction of two values stored in two lists as follows:

```
     import sys,os
     import math

     c1 = [10]
     c2 = [5]
     d1 = [8]
     d2 = [4]


      x = d2 - c2 
      y = d1 - c1
      z = x*x
      w = y*y
      answer = sqrt(z + w)
      print answer
```

My error is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

How can I get over the error that occurs due to subtraction not being possible between two lists, i.e., in lines d2-d1 and c2-c1? Is there a built-in function in the math module similar to sqrt that i might use to subtract lists?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you subtract the lists? Why are you using lists at all?

Comment: You are treating lists as though they were numbers. Why? Either use numbers, or refer to the list contents via, e.g., `c1[0]`. Also - please do not use ALL CAPS, that is regarded as SHOUTING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using one element lists; If you want to perform that calculation specifically, just remove the braces.  I'll assume that you actually do have multi-valued lists.  A reasonable solution is to combine `map()`, which applies a function to each element in one or more lists, as well as some of the functions from the `operator` module, which turn many python operators (like `+` and `-`) into functions.

First well just set up some lists.

```
>>> import random
>>> d1 = [random.randrange(10) for ignored in range(10)]
>>> d2 = [random.randrange(10) for ignored in range(10)]
>>> c1 = [random.randrange(10) for ignored in range(10)]
>>> c2 = [random.randrange(10) for ignored in range(10)]
>>> c1
[1, 1, 7, 5, 5, 7, 4, 0, 7, 2]
>>> c2
[9, 2, 7, 7, 1, 1, 9, 3, 6, 8]
>>> d1
[0, 3, 4, 8, 9, 0, 7, 1, 6, 5]
>>> d2
[3, 9, 5, 2, 1, 9, 2, 7, 9, 5]
```

Next we just replace each of your operations into a `map` call to the corresponding `operator.*`

```
>>> import operator
>>> x = map(operator.sub, d2, c2)
>>> y = map(operator.sub, d2, c2)
>>> z = map(operator.mul, x, x)
>>> w = map(operator.mul, y, y)
>>> import math
>>> answer = map(math.sqrt, map(operator.add, z, w))
>>> print answer
[8.48528137423857, 9.899494936611665, 2.8284271247461903, 7.0710678118654755, 0.0, 11.313708498984761, 9.899494936611665, 5.656854249492381, 4.242640687119285, 4.242640687119285]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
import math

c = [10,5]
d = [8,4]
x = d[1] - c[1]
y = d[0] - c[0]
z = x*x 
w = y*y 

print math.sqrt(z+w)
```

Comment: yes exactly, this a simpler way of doing the same thing. Works well for fewer values in list; like one or two values at most. But for multiple/innumerable values the above code by TokenMacGuy is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't subtract a whole list at once like that, even if there is only one item in the list. You have to do them one at a time. You could do it in a loop, or with a map. Here it is with a map:

```
import operator.sub
map(operator.sub, d2, c2)
map(operator.sub, d1, c1)
```

Comment: in python this is spelled `operator.sub`